# Sitecore Preference Center

Tags: exm

This query is related to **Sitecore Preference Center**.

I am having following queries:

- Is it possible to utilize Sitecore Preference Center for non-Sitecore
  sites?
- As per my understanding we can add different options for
  opt-in/opt-out with the help of manager root and that can be utilized
  as per brand site with customization
  (https://doc.sitecore.com/users/exm/100/email-experience-manager/en/walkthrough--customizing-the-preference-center.html)
  and user's choices will be stored as per manager root and one user
  can subscribe to many manager roots and can be unsubscribe only at
  individual manager root and not from all manager roots at once. Is my
  understanding correct?
- To utilize Sitecore Preference Center, user
  needs to be identified as Contact e.g. email id?
- Any inputs on the performance of Sitecore Preference Center?
- User can subscribe or un-subscribe only from EMAIL sent via EXM or user can directly access the P reference Center link from Sitecore or non-Sitecore websites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I don't see why you couldn't since it's a separate page/service tied to EXM
- Each Email Manager Root can have its own settings that make up the Preference Center for that particular Root. To ensure a user can't "unsubscribe from all roots at once" you should ensure that you use different exclude lists per root and different marketing categories per root.
- The Sitecore Preference Center uses the ec_eq that contains the email and recipient details.
- I don't have any performance results to share but it is a standalone handler (ASHX) and the page itself is simple and plain so I expect it to perform relatively well. As always I recommend you do a performance test against the actual implementation since there are many factors that can impact this.
- The Preference Center is only accessible with a valid ec_eq which is a very complex double-encrypted string that would be impossible to construct without an actual EXM email being received. Hitting the preference center without an ec_eq causes a redirect to home "/".

The handler class is Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd.sitecore_modules.Web.EXM.SubscriptionPreferences

Comment: Thanks for the response Ivan. In terms of non-sitecore need to check shared handler and see how can we generate the link. 
To subscribe to user for particular Message Type, can we utilize Preference Center by opening the URL directly or this should also needs to be come via EXM Email?
Or 
Need to write Marketing Automation Plan to enroll user and add into Contact List?

Also, is there any way to change default location of EXM message from default Email Manager /sitecore/content/Email/ to other EXM Manager location?

Comment: For this " is there any way to change default location of EXM message from default Email Manager /sitecore/content/Email/ to other EXM Manager location?", when you send the email message, it will store to particular EXM Manager location

Comment: There's a rule named "where the contact has (not) subscribed to marketing preference marketing preference for the manager root manager root" you can use to create segmented lists of users with a particular marketing category. You can add this to users in various ways... forms, marketing automation plans... depends on how and what you need. As I mentioned you can't open the Preference Center directly without a valid ec_eq so you need to send an email to invite the user to set their preferences... (this helps with double opt-in requirements)

Comment: A message always belongs to a manager root and you can have as many manager roots as you need. You shouldn't generally move a message. Simply ensure you're sending from the right root by selecting it in the EXM UI.

Comment: is it possible to add Sub-category for Marketing Categories like :
=> Newsletter: via Email , via SMS?
- Newsletter level Marketing Category handled OOTP per contacts, but if we also need to store subcategory interest like Email or SMS?

Comment: No, the current Subscription Center is built to deal with EXM only (mail). Of course it allows for a great deal of modification but if you have that type of requirements I would develop my own custom page to handle the subscription management whilst drawing inspiration from the original.

Comment: Thanks IvanL. I am also thinking to build custom preference centre by considering the requirements otherwise it will be overcomplicated. As per my understanding Sitecore Preference Centre comes with EXM license?

Comment: I haven't tested using the preference center without a valid EXM license.